# Empty flagging history sidebar if you only flagged as spam

Tags: bug, flag-history

On some sites, the only flags I used are spam flags. And in this case, the flagging history sidebar is empty. Example on Drupal Answers:

[image: Empty flagging history]

But on sites where I also have some other flags, the spam flags show up fine in the history.

Comment: Never noticed that before but yeah I get the same, in my case on Math.SE

Comment: @animuson You're right, haven't seen that one. Voted to close.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Well that question could use some clarification so that it more clearly describes the actual issue. I almost didn't even click on it myself. I'm going to bed though and don't feel like editing right now.

Comment: @animuson I've edited that question.